# How can i play video in openCV with audio the same time

Tags: python-3.x, macos-mojave, opencv, python

I'm trying to play video using openCV but it only show video without sound can you help me to resolve that please, Here is my code.

(
I have a macOS Mojave
version 10.14.6
)

```
import cv2

from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer


video = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/nature.mp4')
player = MediaPlayer('videos/nature.mp4')

while True:
    # read video frame by frame
    isTrue, frame = video.read()
    audio_frame, val = player.get_frame()
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    
    if val != 'eof' and audio_frame is not None:
        #audio
        img, t = audio_frame
    
    if cv2.waitKey(28) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried with **ffpyplayer** but i got this error on my **macOS**.

```
mugisha-MBP:openCV jclaude$ python3 read.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/SCRIPT/openCV/read.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffpyplayer/player/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ffpyplayer.player.player import MediaPlayer
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffpyplayer/player/player.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _objc_opt_class
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffpyplayer/player/../.dylibs/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ffpyplayer/player/../.dylibs/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
```